# How can I build a single project in eclipse to jar file and don't need to choose from many lauch configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

Why are there so many build configurations in eclipse?

It took me a lot of time to choose which build configuration is used to build one project.

Is there any simpler way to build a project?
[image: Image of multiple configurations]

Comment: All those class have `public static void main(String a[])` method in it remove the method from the classes except the actual main class.

Comment: Delete the _Java Application_ run configurations that are not required any more in _Run > Run Configurations..._. If you often want to build the same JAR, use the _Save as ANT script_ option or use Maven, Gradle, etc. for that.

Comment: The jar could be also generated using a bash/batch script...